# Double authentication in rest api

Tags: python, django, api, rest, request

I am trying to get the rest API data in python using the request module. I am using double authentication in my API. When I run the code, I got error 401 but this is working perfectly on postman

```
import requests
response = requests.get('http://localhost:8285/x/1/mindie?C=dfghdh&SDate=01-05-2022&EDate=02-05-2022', headers={'Authorization': 'Basic dweeytdvgccsbj','Authorization': 'Basic fhgvecdjfvnhi'})
s = response.json()
print(response)
```

Comment: You are passing a dict in header. A dict cannot have 2 same key `Authorization`. So request must be passing only one such header.

Comment: I tried this but it is showing keyword argument repeated.

Comment: What do you mean by "double authentication"? Can you add  your authentication config/workflow to the question? What headers does your postman request actually send?